# JSON Deseralize Object - .NET

Tags: .net, json

If I have an object, I can serailize the object like this.

```
 Dim js = New JavaScriptSerializer()
 Dim serialized = js.Serialize(oMyObject)
```

Now I want to reverse the process and turn serialized string back into an object?

I tried a few different ways and keep getting errors. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You keep getting errors? OK, care to provide some more context to your question before it gets closed? For example you may show the JSON string that you have as well as the .NET object that you are trying to deserialize it to. Also showing the exact error message you are getting would be beneficial. It's basically the steps of [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that you provide a minimal and concise example allowing us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: This is a simple question and most likely a one line answer. Close it if you like, but it's totally fine the way it is.

Comment: Yes, it is a line liner: `Dim deserialized = js.Deserialize(Of MyModel)(oMyJsonString)`. Doesn't this simple line work for you? If the answer to this question is **no**, then please go ahead and provide more context about your problem as I asked in my first comment. You mentioned something about getting some errors or something? Caring to provide some more context about your problem?

Comment: Yeah that works Dimitrov, before the edit you were wrong, but it's right now, When I went to test it,I came up with the same solution. But you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, I didn't specify the Object type in the Deserialize method.

```
Dim myObject as ObjectToConvert
Dim js = New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim serialized = js.Serialize(oMyObject)

js.Deserialize(Of ObjectToConvert)(js.Serialize(oMyObject))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = {"myinfo" : {    "id" : 12345,    "name" : "myname"}}
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.DeserializeObject(str);
```

Does this help you ?